# FaceletContext.includeFacelet trouble

Tags: jsf, dynamic, enterprise

I am currently trying to insert pre-defined jsf pages into a particular portion of a main jsf page.  I have been able to achieve this semi-successfully using the following:

```
public void includeFacelet(String pageString){
     //NOTE SEE BELOW
     centerPanelGrid.getParent().getChildren().clear();

     centerPanelGrid.getChildren().clear();

     String actualPath = "faceletFolder/".concat(pageString).concat(".xhtml");

     try{
          FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext)facesContext.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
          faceletContext.includeFacelet(centerPanelGrid, actualPath);
     }catch(IOException ex){
          ...         
     }
}
```

Where the centerPanelGrid is a field variable in my managed bean (dynamicComponentBean) which is bound to a HtmlPanelGrid within the main jsf page and the actualPath variable is the relative path indicating the location of the jsf page.

As for the note, it may seem like non-sense to have to have that line (trust me I realize that) however in all of my tests if I didn't have that line then when I went to include the jsf page it wouldn't include anything...

This is an outline of the main jsf page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>User Page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="45" header="header"/>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" resizable="true">
                [Footer Text]
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" resizable="true">
                [West Content]
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" resizable="true">
                [East Content]
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true" id="dynamicLayout">
                 <h:panelGrid id="dynamicContent" binding="#{dynamicComponentBean.centerPanelGrid}"/>
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And a small example of a page that could get inserted into the centerPanelGrid would be as follws:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Reports Interface</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="rightalign,leftalign,leftalign">

                <h:outputText value="Find Daily Report"/>
                <p:calendar id="dailyCalendar" value="#{reports.dailyDate}" mode="popup" effect="slide"/>
                <h:commandButton id="findDailyReport" value="Search" action="#{dynamicComponentBean.includeFacelet('navString')}"/>

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:message for="dailyCalendar"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

With navString being whatever String I pass to it so that the includeFacelet method can pull the appropriate jsf to insert next.

My problem arises when I try to use the command button to navigate, it requires me to press it twice to work, the first press makes it seem like it refreshes the page or something and then the subsequent click allows me to include the correct facelet in the centerPanelGrid.

I have done extensive debugging on the issuse and I have found that during the first click it is making no calls to any method within any of my managed beans and is not actually going into any of my code for that matter.  I have no idea why it is doing this or what I need to do to get it to just include the facelet that I want and have it navigate normally.

In essence these web pages come from an additional enterprise application that was developed seperately and integrated into the current system. The current system does all page generation through manually creating the java objects that represent all of the various UIComponents and putting them into their appropriate place. However short of creating seperate stateles session beans to generate all of these various pages in a similar fashion I have set it up to know when these pages from the integrated application are being called and to instead put them into the dynamic component panel using the includeFacelet method.

Comment: good question. I will check it, after I finished with my work

Comment: Any reason you cannot use something like `ui:include src="#{dynamicComponent.currentPath}"` instead of processing facelets programmatically?

Comment: @mrembisz The `ui:include` component will only work on another XHTML page and one that has a `ui:composition` tag.  From the sound of it the OP is dealing with third party pages that he may not have control over.

Comment: @maple_shaft The example given in question contains extra head, body. I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to include such unadapted page anyway. Perhaps some versions of some browsers won't mind. If there is no way to adapt these pages I'd consider iframe or similar.

Comment: @mrembisz I agree, without knowing more about these other pages I would say that an iframe is the only way to go.

Comment: I have tested the includeFacelet method with pages that do and dont contain the extra head and body tags it works the same both ways.
As for the ui:include everything is dynamically placed within the center layout unit and as far as I can tell there is no java class equivalent for that particular tab.  
The problem is that I need to display all of the dynamic content within the center layout unit and as it is now it works but it almost appears as if it is not in sync with the page it is inserted into until after the first click of the command button

Comment: Also this works exactly the same regardless of what browser it is run in and any insight as to how I would go about using the iframe to accomplish this I have tried several ways but all of them end up just erasing what is meant to be displayed and only display a frame with nothing in it inside of the center layout unit

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
faceletContext.includeFacelet(centerPanelGrid.getParent(), actualPath);
```